# Не получается запустить библиотеку Fetch для загрузки файлов из слушателя нажатия кнопки

Tags: android, fetch

Решил использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) для загрузки файлов. Предыдущая версия работала нормально, но ее обновили. При установке нового варианта библиотеки никак не могу добиться корректного кода - студия красит код, начинающийся mFetch.enqueue. Помогите понять, что не так? Делаю все по примеру в документации.

```
public class BookCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    private int bookId;
    Fetch mFetch;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_card);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        mFetch = (Fetch) new Fetch.Builder(this, "ToddlerBook")
                .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(4)
                .enableLogging(true)
                .build();

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHome);
        View.OnClickListener clickHome = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GoHome();
            }
        };

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(clickHome);

        BookUriFromId();

        String fileNamePath = "filesPath.json";
        String covers = MyJSON.getData(this, fileNamePath);
        ArrayList<String> coversPaths = getFilesPathFromFile(covers);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int posit = bookId - 1;
        File imgFile = new File(coversPaths.get(posit));
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        final Button buttonDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        /**
         * Проверим наличие файлов в папке bookfiles_1, bookfiles_2, ...
         */
        String folderBook = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        int count = 0;
        /**
         * Проверяем необходимость загрузки файлов
         */

        File rootFile = new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(folderBook)));
        File[] filesArray = rootFile.listFiles();
        int numbFiles = filesArray.length;
        if (numbFiles == 0) {

            buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonDownload);
            /**
             * Загрузим json с url файлов книги
             */

            Thread jsDownload = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BookLoader();
                }
            });
            jsDownload.start(); // запустили поток 1

            /**
             * Обрабатываем нажатие кнопки "Загрузить" и грузим файлы книги
             */

            buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                            String fileListB = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";
                            String jsReadFile = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileListB);
                            Log.d(TAG, jsReadFile);
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Book book = gson.fromJson(jsReadFile, Book.class);
                            List<String> pages = book.getPageUrl();
                            List<String> sounds = book.getSoundUrl();
                            String[] urlsPages = pages.toArray(new String[0]);
                            String[] urlsSounds = sounds.toArray(new String[0]);
                            String[] urlsFiles = ArrayAndArrayNewArray(urlsPages, urlsSounds);

                            String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
                            String fileNameForWrite = "book_" + bookId + ".json";

                            final List<Request> requestList = new ArrayList<>();

                            File bookfolder = new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(folderB)));
                            ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < urlsFiles.length; i++) {

                                String url = urlsFiles[i];
                                String path = String.valueOf(bookfolder);
                                String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
                                Log.d("my2", fileName);
                                String pageFilePath = path + "/" + fileName;

                                final Request request = new Request(url, pageFilePath);
                                request.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
                                request.setNetworkType(NetworkType.ALL);

                                requestList.add(request);

//            Log.d("my2", pageFilePath);
                                pagesFiles.add(pageFilePath);

                            }
// ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!!
                            mFetch.enqueue(requestList, new Func<List<? extends Download>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(List<? extends Download> downloads) {
                                    //Successfully enqueued requests.
                                }
                            }, new Func<Error>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Error error) {
                                    // An error occurred when enqueuing requests.
                                }
                            });

                            BookFiles bookFiles = new BookFiles();
                            bookFiles.setBookID(bookId);

                            ArrayList<String> pagesPath = getPagesArray(pagesFiles);
                            ArrayList<String> soundsPath = getSoundsArray(pagesFiles);

                            bookFiles.setPagesPath(pagesPath);
                            bookFiles.setSoundsPath(soundsPath);
                            Gson gson11 = new Gson();
                            String filesJson = gson11.toJson(bookFiles);

                            MyJSON.saveData(getApplicationContext(), filesJson, fileNameForWrite);


                    buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
                    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            NextActivity();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
            buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NextActivity();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void BookUriFromId() {
        //получаем номер ID книги, с обложки которой перешли в слайдер
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "You read book №" + bookId);
    }

    private void NextActivity() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BookCardActivity.this, SliderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bookId", bookId); // передаю в слайдер номер книги

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 20);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getFilesPathFromFile(String jsResult) {
        ArrayList<String> urisImg = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray rootJson = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(jsResult));
            for (int i = 0; i < rootJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = rootJson.getJSONObject(i);
                String strTo = (String) o.get("uriString");
                urisImg.add(strTo);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urisImg;
    }

    private void BookLoader() {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJsonServer = "";
        String fileBook = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";

        try {
            String jsUrl = "http://******.ru/todbook/book" + bookId + ".json";
            URL url = new URL(jsUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            resultJsonServer = buffer.toString();
            MyJSON.saveData(getApplicationContext(), resultJsonServer, fileBook);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String[] ArrayAndArrayNewArray(String[] a, String[] b) {
        if (a == null)
            return b;
        if (b == null)
            return a;
        String[] r = new String[a.length + b.length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, r, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, r, a.length, b.length);
        return r;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSoundsArray(ArrayList<String> pagesFiles) {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesFiles.size(); i++) {
            String soun = pagesFiles.get(i);
            if (soun.contains("sound")) {
                res.add(soun);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPagesArray(ArrayList<String> pagesFiles) {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesFiles.size(); i++) {
            String soun = pagesFiles.get(i);
            if (!soun.contains("sound")) {
                res.add(soun);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private void GoHome() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BookCardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10);
    }

}
```

Comment: Уточню, что пробовал сделать тестовый загрузчик в новой, чистой активити - результат тот же. Студия красит тот же участок кода

Comment: Когда `Студия красит тот же участок кода`, она же и говорит, что не так.

Comment: Не в этот раз...

Comment: вы пробовали навести мышь на красное и узнать,  что не нравится студии?

Comment: да, выходит что-то cannot resolve method enqueune и дальше название библиотеки

Comment: Может быть список параметров неверный?

Comment: Так ничего и не понял, копировал код в новый проект строго по мануалу. Бесполезно. Не работает. Сношу  библиотеку